# how to tell nose and coverage not to include files in my virtualenv?

Tags: nosetests, coverage.py

I'm trying to wrangle nose + coverage.  If I have this code:

```
class Foobar(object):
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

And this test:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from foobar import Foobar

class FoobarTest(TestCase):
    def test_good(self):
        f = Foobar()
        self.assertEquals(f.add(1,2), 3)
```

Then everything looks good!

```
$ nosetests
.
Name        Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------
foobar.py       3      0   100%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.018s

OK
```

But if I add one line to my source code

```
import requests

class Foobar(object):
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

then I get lots of extra stuff in my report

```
$ nosetests
.
Name                                                                           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
foobar.py                                                                      4      0   100%
requests.py                                                                   26      5    81%   54, 72-75
requests/adapters.py                                                         180    134    26%   48, 51, 54, 89-102, 105, 111-117, 1

[snip]
```

So how do I configure coverage to say "don't bother measuring or reporting anything that is part of my virtualenv -- just do the stuff under my working directory."  I'm sure it has something to do with .coveragerc, but I'm having some trouble getting the invocation correct.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

1) Get rid of any coverage-related ini files

2) add this in "nose.cfg" *in your home directory* for the nose stuff

```
[nosetests]
with-coverage=1   ; generate a coverage report (in the "cover" directory)
cover-package=.   ; only report on coverage files in the current directory
cover-html=1      ; generate a pretty html report
cover-erase=1     ; re-generate coverage statistics on each run
```

and of course, you have to be sure that your test files match the testMatch pattern that Nose is looking for.